# Как оптимально произвести замену шорткодов на текст через чистый javascript?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно разработать код на чистом javascript без фреймворков типа jquery. Прошу от Вас совета.

Задачи которые он выполняет:

1. получает из URL цифровой параметр
2. делает запрос к сайту сервиса, получая список замен
3. Заменяет определенные шорткоды на сайте на заданный текст. Например {description} на "текст".

Требования:

1. чтобы замена производилась как в самом тексте, например: `<div class="one">{description}</div>`
2. так и в самом теге, например: `<div class="{description}">Текст</div>` (если это технически возможно)
3. чтобы замены производились сразу по мере загрузки DOM-дерева, т.к. если вставлять их после загрузки - вначале видно шорт-код, который через несколько секунд меняется на текст замены, а желательно, чтобы замену было видно сразу. Если это технически возможно
4. чтобы скрипт не конфликтовал с другими скриптами сайта.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше это реализовать, буду благодарен за примеры, названия функций и краткие пояснения. Спасибо!

Comment: А почему бы вам просто не использовать шаблонизатор для этих целей?

Comment: Вот тут например есть подборка https://habrahabr.ru/post/219873 можете заглянуть в их исходники, если вам очень хочется свой собственный велосипед.

Comment: Задача - требования. это ж не сайт разработки ПЗ. Разрабатывать тут не будут.

Comment: @nick_n_a, с другой стороны, автор и код не требует :-)

Comment: @Grundy, лучше б в ответе рпассказал, почему это сделать не получится и/или так не надо делать...

Comment: @Qwertiy а почему не получится - если долго мучится что-нибудь получится. Посидеть денёк второй - задачу сделать можно. Ну пункт 4 не очень уверен - а остальное реализуемо.

Comment: @nick_n_a, ну так пункт 4 все и ломает :)

Comment: @Grundy Тестирование покажет:) так сложно сказать.

Comment: @Grundy, а как ты собрался реализовать 3? Да ещё и с ajax-запросами? Они синхронные будут?

Comment: @Qwertiy, например, загружать разметку страницы тоже по запросу, получать Html в виде текста, обработать его заменив все что надо и вставить куда-нить в innerHtml, проблема будет только если в теле будут теги script, они потеряются. На и всегда можно просто скрывать необработанные элементы. А еще можно попробовать посмотреть в сторону MutationObserver но тут не уверен совсем

Comment: @Grundy, `<input> {smeAttr}={someValue} />` - не прокатит innertHTML. И вообще, по сути у тебя шаблонизатор и получится, а не вывод по мере загрузки.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну так тут и так невалидный html, результат не изменится - редактировать его или нет. По мере загрузки вполне мог бы помочь MutatioObserver

Comment: @Grundy, с удовольствием посмотрю пример в ответе :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, если доберусь до этого :-)